# Loading Any USB Flash Drive onto an iOS Device

Tags: iphone, ios, hard-drive, usb, filesystem

I have a SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 flash drive with 32 GB storage on it, and would like to view its contents on my iPhone. I have seen flash drives that are made particularly for iOS devices and have their own companion apps for viewing the files, but I already have this flash drive, and would like to be able to use it or any other flash drive for that matter on my phone.

So far, I have looked into using adapters that I can use to plug the flash drive into my phone using the lightning cable, but have only found micro USB adapters.

Another issues is that I am unsure of how I would view the files even if I could connect the flash drive to my iPhone; would I need a special file browser like this, or is there an app I an use?

In general, then:

Is there any way to load any run-of-the-mill flash drive onto an iPhone and view its contents, whether through an app or a file browser (installed on the device)?